# How to implement clean Next.js URL in graphql-yoga

Tags: node.js, graphql, next.js

I am creating a GraphQL app using Next.js for server side rendering. As you might know, there is a recommended way to implement clean URL using Express. I am trying to achieve the same using graphql-yoga but it's not working.

I have tried `server.express.get('/route', ...)` and `server.get('/route', ...)` but nothing is working. In the documentation they have given `server.express.get(server.options.endpoint, handler())` but it's not working for me.

Has anyone ever implemented clean Next.js URL in a GraphQL Yoga server, and how did you achieve it? Below is how I am creating the server.

```
function createServer() {
  return new GraphQLServer({
    typeDefs: "src/schema.graphql",
    resolvers: {
      Mutation,
      Query
    },
    context: req => ({ ...req, db })
  });
}


const server = createServer();

server.express.post('/product/name', (req,res,next) => {
  //this is where i want to implement next clean url
  //but it's not working
  console.log('Am never reached..');
  next();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

With the new versions of Next.js, creating clean URL is straightforward.

Create a parameterised page (e.g. `pages/post/[pid].js`):

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const Post = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { pid } = router.query

  return <p>Post: {pid}</p>
}

export default Post
```

More info in the [Next.js documentation regarding dynamic routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes).

You can then link to it and show the desired URL:

```
<Link href="/post/[pid]" as="/post/abc">
  <a>First Post</a>
</Link>
```